# What is the difference between "for some way" and "in some way"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is meant by "for some way" in this sentence? Could it be a mistake? Should it be "in some way"?

> But when the Rabbit actually TOOK A WATCH OUT OF ITS WAISTCOAT-POCKET, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.
>
> In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.
>
> The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel **for some way**, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.
>
> — *[Alice's Adventures in Wonderland](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/aliceinwonderland-1.html)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't a mistake. The tunnel was horizontal **for some distance** and then suddenly became a vertical shaft which Alice fell down.

(I recognise this as a passage from *Alice in Wonderland*, but you really should tell us the source of a quotation that you are asking about.)

Comment: [Definition #6 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way) (as opposed to definition #4)